# Decoding serial data package

Tags: hex, serial-communication, protocol

I have an assignment at work, to get information from Jenbacher generator and show values in new  SCADA system. It has a B&R CP260 PLC with RS232 port and RS232 to RS485 converter. Currently it’s connected to old Winows XP PC via COM port. From hardware settings on PC I can see that it uses **9600 baud 8N1**. It **sends data packets every 5 seconds (without request)**. There is about 30 different variables that are shown in the old SCADA system (a lot of BOOLs and about 8 analog values. **The whole system is 15 years old**. I used RealTerm to read 10 packages in HEX and I got some data.

I wrote down active power from screen with every packet received and I have some variables that are not changing so often (didn’t change while reading packets) :

Operating hours – **81521**

Total active power – **80578,3**

Total reactive power – **1053,5**

Active power from screen whit each packet received:

1)  **852** kW

2)  **853** kW

3)  **843** kW

4)  **840** kW

5)  **851** kW

6)  **856** kW

7)  **848** kW

8)  **841** kW

9)  **848** kW

10) **852** kW

Active power is changing on screen with every packet received, so it must be sending power updates with every packet, but I can’t find it in the packet. I found Op hours, total active, reactive power in some packets, but it is not consistent.

*Update:*

Discovered values in **bold** :

**13E71** - OP hours

**C4B97** - Tot. active power

**2927** - Tot. reactive power

Data:

```
1)
FF01020810408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010000010408A060AA15B8010208
10408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204040AA03490308DB405360010428
3052000004420102081040BF2101F404F0056B0A10406024023F09C3265891608D022D09534D5869
6021024A024E09034D5869601B0248091B4DD89A602460A3024E016268D239800029270D8A0D5060
16020850630C20400000000114CC1440800000000114AC2040000000010408204000000A7100CC00
C80154018D055B2A58D440D6FF8C0391234CAB2022C1F600860024012A03A105B60D2040000006A1
01040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000
01040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000
0104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000ED

2)

FF01020810408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010000010408A060AA15B8010208
10408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001F40104082040000000
01040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000
010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000FD0134A8A540A900D003BD0AEC010428
3052000004420102081040BF2201F404D1056B0A104060D202400239097324183360170248094B4D
984860D2024E09FB24589A602360D202430250093B499834602700182DBA0E1040CA270341022898
16020850630C20400000000114CC14408000000001142C3040000000010408204000000A75016400
CA00CA018D055B2A58D440D5FF880DFA899859811304DB00430091012A03E8014B0000000003E800
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000FB

3)

FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000080010000000001148CB53157000000010408
20400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000FE0104082040000000010408
20400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408
204000000001040820400000000104082040000000FD013468D2406A006703BD0AEC010428305200
0004420102081040BF2001F404CD018E010248586960900239097324582360170247094B4D984860
D2024E09FB24589A602360D20243024F024709334D981240834B970000A57634503580C03E710102
28EC0C20400000000114AC1440800000000104880104082040000000010408A020F700E600CA00CA
018E05632E98D440D2FF990DEA8D98AC818704BF008401042A3065407401320000010468205D0000
00010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000
00010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000
00010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204087

4)

FF01020810408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010000010408A060AA15B8010208
10408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
0820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820404024034903E8DB405B60010428
3052000004420102081040BF2101F404F3056B0A104060D2024209CB24D899608D022E092B4D5869
6021024A024E09FB24589A608D02490243024E093B499834602700182DBA0E1040CA270341022898
16020850630C20400000000114AC1440800000000104A8000001040820400000000154A80B203E80
F900E5018D055B2A58D44096FF8D0D3A234C5E208382D3008401E42A306540740143000001046820
5D000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820
40000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820
40000000010408204000000001040820400000000104083040000000000000007DFF

5)
FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000080010000000000015415B800000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000010408204000034D1A480DA0B640B701FF0102281852800002420102081040BF2201F404
EC018D010248586960688139098324982360170244094B4D984860A5024E09FB24589A608D024A02
43024D093B49D824602700182DBA0E1040CA27034102289816020850630C204000000001148C1C40
8000000001140C1840800000000104082040000575016400CA00CA018D055B2A58D440D7FF8903A1
23ECAB206482E8011A0D1052C02A03A10596020810408003E8010208104080000000010408204000
00000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000
00000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000
000001040820400000000104082040000090

6)

FF01020810408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010000010408A060AA15B8010208
10408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001F40104082040000000
01040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000
010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000FD0134086D206A006803B90BCC000005
060A204081420102081040BF2201F404D4056B0A104060D202430238023009B32498916068814902
4209534DD89A6024589A608D024A0243024C0247093B49981240834B970000A57634102580C03E71
010228EC0C204000000001148C1C408000000001140C1840800000000104082040000575016400CA
00CA018D055B2A58D440DA2135E835B0579020C11640480091012A03A105D60D2040000006A10104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000009FD

7)

FF01020810408000000001040820400000000104082040000080010000010608F060FF15B8000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FF000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000FF00035003520067036D01FF000001900000024200000000FC2201F404
CC018E0000024902430238022F0235022E024202490241024A024F023F0249023502490242024B02
470247024E000C4B9700002927035000023E71010228EC0C20400000000114AC1440800000000114
8C3040000000010408204000000A75016400CA00CA018E05632E98D440492937881AB0F0810A04D1
0112091052C02A03A105B6061020800003A101040820400000000104082040000000010408204000
00000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000
00000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000
000001040820400000006DFF

8)

FF01020810408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010000010408A060AA15B8010208
10408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204040D2035200D003B5130C104080
0190010248984880000000F181168C3F30F8C08D000009964D30488138022E09AB24989160488149
024109534DD89A6024589A602360D2024209534DD8246024602700182DBA0E1040CA270341022898
16020850630C20400000000114CC1440800000000104A8000001040820400000000154880F203E80
F900E5018E055B2A58D44094FF950DDA8D182BC1FF04C60112099054606540740139010208104040
74000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040
00000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040
0000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040003B

9)

FF01020810408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010000010408A060AA15B8010208
10408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104
08204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040830408000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035003520067036D020000000190000002
4200000000FC2101F404F3018D0000024902420239022E0234022D024102490241024A024F023F02
490236024A0241024902460247024E000C4B9700002927034F00013E710000191F00000000000001
8D00000000000000FC0000000000000000000005DB00E600E500E5018D018B018D035BFF8D036704
C3050D04D500430090012A03E8015C0000000003A101040820400000000104082040000000010408
20400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408
20400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408
2040000000010408204000000091FF

10)

FF01020810408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010000010408A060AA15B8010208
10408000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001F40104082040000000
01040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000
010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000FD013488B540A900CE03B50BEC010428
3052000004420102081040BF2101F404E1056B0A104060D2024109CB24589160CD022D090B495869
6090024A024F023F094B4D982360A50241094B4D98346024602700182DBA0E1040CA270341022898
16020850630C204000000001148C1C40800000000114EC3040000000010408204000000A7D00CC00
CA00CA018D055B2A58D440A531374889305A811C04E5008401142E3065407401610000010468205D
00000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040
00000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040
000000010408204000000001040820400000000104082040000000010408204069
```

Comment: It might be useful if you annotated the fields you already decoded in the packet dumps.

Comment: Done! As i mentioned, it's not consistent. I can see values in some packets, but maybe it is coincidence and i'm reading it wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I got it working, turns out I used wrong parity, din't know you can override davice manager port settings from VB. Thanks.